# Sum distinct values for first occurance in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

In Power BI I have some duplicate entries in my data that only have 1 column that is different, this is a "details" column.

```
Name   | Value | Details
Item 1 | 10    | Feature 1
Item 1 | 10    | Feature 2
Item 2 | 15    | Feature 1
Item 3 | 7     | Feature 1
Item 3 | 7     | Feature 2
Item 3 | 7     | Feature 3
```

I realize this is an issue with the data structure, but it cannot be changed.

Basically, when I sum up my Value column on a Power BI card, I only want it to sum for each unique name, so in this case:

```
Total = 10 + 15 + 7
```

I will be using the details in a matrix, so I cannot simply remove the duplicates from within the Query Editor.

Is there any way I can filter this with a DAX formula? Just summing the first occurrence of an item?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can create a measure as follows:

```
Total = SUMX(DISTINCT(Data[Name]), FIRSTNONBLANK(Data[Value], 0))
```

It will return the first non-blank `Value` for all distinct `Name` and sum it up.

Results:

[image: results]

Answer (score 0):

This must help

```
Table = SUMMARIZE(Sheet2,Sheet2[Item],"Sales Quantity",SUM(Sheet2[Sales Quantiy]),"Purchase Quantity",CALCULATE(SUMX(DISTINCT(Sheet2[Purchase Quantity]),FIRSTNONBLANK(Sheet2[Purchase Quantity],0))))
```