# DAX Measure: dynamically consider only first for each group and and overall returns their count

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

We are struggling in trying to solve a problem that might simpler than I think. I am just stuck.

The problem consists of defining a `DAX Measure` that **dynamically** counts only **first** visits in the period **for each patient**. Visits that are **not first** in the period must be **assigned BLANK()** value.
Please before discussing the goal let me introduce the scenario.

1. Scenario:
   We have a model composed of one fact table (`F_Visits`) and two dimensions (`D_Customer`; `D_Calendar`). 
   `F_Visits` has 1M records and contains all visits made by customers into the Clothing shop. Its fields are:
   `Visit Id`:     Incremental unique number which is the natural key of the table
   `Customer Fk`:  Foreign Key of dimension D_Customer in the fact table
   `Calendar Fk`:  Foreign Key of dimension D_Calendar in the fact table
   `Quantity`:         Number of cloth pieces purchased in the visit
   `Amount`:       Amount of dollars spent in the visit
   `Seller`:       Employee name who served the customer
2. Goal:
   Create a Measure that:

   - dynamically (based on the time period selection)
   - **for each visit within each customer** return the value `1` if it is the first for that patient in the selected period **(minimum Visit Id in the period)**,
     ignoring visits that are not the first in the selected time period for each customer
   - **overall (in total)** this measure needs to return count of total number of **first visits** made by all patients in the selected time period

I have been searching on online communities for the last two weeks but found no problem like mine.
A similar (but different) one is the following: [Sum distinct values for first occurance in Power BI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43547620/sum-distinct-values-for-first-occurance-in-power-bi)
The main difference compared to that question is the measure for this problem needs to be BLANK() for visits that are not the first of that patient in the selected period.
3. Example:

```
+----------+-------------+-------------+----------+--------+--------+
| Visit Id | Customer FK | Calendar FK | Quantity | Amount | Seller |
+----------+-------------+-------------+----------+--------+--------+
|        1 | John        |    20170101 |        1 |     10 | Rick   |
|        2 | John        |    20180101 |        2 |     15 | Morty  |
|        3 | John        |    20180101 |        3 |     17 | Eric   |
|        4 | John        |    20190101 |        2 |     17 | Eric   |
|        5 | Mark        |    20170101 |        1 |     17 | Eric   |
|        6 | Mark        |    20180101 |        3 |     12 | Eric   |
|        7 | Jack        |    20190101 |        0 |      0 | Rick   |
+----------+-------------+-------------+----------+--------+--------+
```

4. Solution:
   The user now filter for Calendar FK = 2018. This will exclude some visit 
   and the measure is dynamically calculated to count only first vists in the selected period for each patient:

**Detail Table**:

```
+----------+-------------+-------------+----------+--------+--------+---------+
| Visit Id | Customer FK | Calendar FK | Quantity | Amount | Seller | Measure |
+----------+-------------+-------------+----------+--------+--------+---------+
|        2 | John        |    20180101 |        2 |     15 | Morty  | 1       |
|        3 | John        |    20180101 |        3 |     17 | Eric   | BLANK() |
|        6 | Mark        |    20180101 |        3 |     12 | Eric   | 1       |
+----------+-------------+-------------+----------+--------+--------+---------+
```

**Total**:

```
+-------+
| Total |
+-------+
|     2 |
+-------+
```

**Total by Seller**:

```
+--------+---------+
| Seller | Measure |
+--------+---------+
| Morty  | 1       |
| Eric   | 1       |
| Rick   | BLANK() |
+--------+---------+
```

There is no specific requirements about the approach except it needs to be dynamically calculated on front end.

### Update

please refer to question [DAX: avoid ALL() causing incorrect show of dimensional attribute in matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58283254/dax-avoid-all-causing-incorrect-show-of-dimensional-attribute-in-matrix)

Comment: is update clear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
First Visit =
// Make a table of all patients in context and their first visit id in context
VAR PatientFirstVisits =
  ADDCOLUMNS (
    VALUES ( 'F_Visits'[Customer Fk] ),
    "MinVisitId", CALCULATE (
        MIN ( 'F_Visits'[Visit Id] ),
        ALL ( 'F_Visits'[Visit Id], 'F_Visits'[Seller] ), // note: fragile
        ALLSELECTED ( 'D_Calendar' )
    )
  )
RETURN
  // Count the Visit Ids that are associated with one of the patient-visit pairs in
  // PatientFirstVisits
  CALCULATE ( 
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'F_Visits'[Visit Id] ),
    KEEPFILTERS ( TREATAS ( PatientFirstVisits, 'F_Visits'[Customer Fk], 'F_Visits'[Visit Id] ) )
  )
```

Note on the fragile part, it is a best practice to construct fact tables of only FKs and aggregateable facts, i.e. do not have any descriptive attributes in the fact table. The reason the commented part is fragile is that you will need to add to the `ALL` any new descriptive columns you add to the fact that may end up in a visual with this measure. If you pull seller out to a dim, you can refactor as below:

```
First Visit = 
VAR PatientFirstVisits =
  ADDCOLUMNS (
    VALUES ( 'F_Visits'[Customer Fk] ),
    "MinVisitId", CALCULATE (
        MIN ( 'F_Visits'[Visit Id] ),
        ALL ( 'F_Visits'[Visit Id] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( 'D_Calendar' ),
        ALL ( 'Seller' )
    )
  )
RETURN
  CALCULATE ( 
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'F_Visits'[Visit Id] ),
    KEEPFILTERS ( TREATAS ( PatientFirstVisits, 'F_Visits'[Customer Fk], 'F_Visits'[Visit Id] ) )
  )
```

Based on my experience, columns within a table are about an order of magnitude more volatile than tables within a model. What I mean by this is that I typically see much more churn in columns (adding, removing, refactoring in some way) than churn in tables. By pulling out a 'Seller' dim, you can just do `ALL ( 'Seller' )` and you don't have to worry about tracking columns.

And here's the measure in action:

[image: measure in a visual]

**Edit:** A version based on the comment asking if we can do a `COUNTROWS` version rather than `DISTINCTCOUNT`. The VAR would be the same, so I'm just showing the count after the `RETURN`.

```
...
RETURN
  // Count the Visit Ids that are associated with one of the patient-visit pairs in
  // PatientFirstVisits
  COUNTROWS ( 
    INTERSECT (
      GROUPBY( 'F_visits', 'F_visits'[Customer FK], 'F_visits'[Visit Id] ),
      PatientFirstVisits
    )
  )
```

Here we just intersect the VAR table and the values in context from the fact. That intersect is 1 row or empty for detail rows, and it is the total without being filtered by 'F_Visits'[Visit Id].

Comment: I will follow your suggestion and eventually build you a Statue! One question: is there a way to obtain the same result but instead of using a DISTINCTCOUNT() do something like COUNTROWS(FILTER('''consider only first vist in the period''')) exploiting the fact that each customer can have only one first visit in the period? Thank you :)

Comment: I expect `COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( ... ) )` would likely be worse, performance-wise, as `FILTER` would have to iterate the table, and iteration is generally slower than set-based operations in DAX. You are right that `DISTINCTCOUNT` is probably not needed. You might just use `COUNT` instead. Or you could just `COUNTROWS ( 'F_Visits' )`. The filtering is already handled by `CALCULATE`, and generally you should prefer `CALCULATE` with set-based filters.

Comment: Actually, that is a great question. I probably responded too quickly. Adding an edit to the answer with an alternative.

Comment: Great @greggyb, thank you VERY MUCH! Please give me a couple of days to test and make sure this works. Also, I will perform comparison on DAX Studio to show the two different approaches you proposed and post them here for completeness.

Comment: The solution highly impact loading time of the report (from 2 to 5 seconds) because requires lot of additional effort from Formula Engine. The slow down is acceptable considering the complexity of this calculation. I opted to not use the GROUPBY solution because the number of customer grouped is several hundredth thousands and cause inefficiency on the GROUPBY.

Comment: this would deserve a new question but it is too much specific to your answer. I am trying to modify the context such that: PatientFirstVisits is calculated YTD, regardless of Calendar slicers selection. The issue is that when I apply the same context transition to the CALCULATE after RETURN, the formula breaks and returns 1 to every record. Any hint please?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're looking for, but I think you should start by switching the definition for "MinVisitId" to use `ALL ( 'D_Calendar' ), VALUES ( 'D_Calendar'[Year] )`. This will preserve only year filters when deriving that value. You may need to do something similar in the other `CALCULATE` as well. I'd really need to see a more thorough spec or a mockup to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I tried to update the question, I could create a new question but I really do not know how to explain it since it is strictly related to this question. In my solution I tried to use KEEPFILTERS but seems to not be the correct one, or I did not use it in the correct way. Hope in some hints, thanks