# DAX: avoid ALL() causing incorrect show of dimensional attribute in matrix

Tags: powerbi, dax

Following the useful answer to my [previous DAX question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57786786/dax-measure-dynamically-consider-only-first-for-each-group-and-and-overall-retu), I found myself facing a new, different problem for which I ask your help in this new question:

#### 1. Scenario:

We have a model composed of one fact table (`F_Visits`) and one dimension `D_Calendar`. 
`F_Visits` is the fact table and contains all visits made by customers into the Clothing shop. Its fields are:
`Visit Id`:     Incremental unique number which is the natural key of the table
`Customer Key`: Unique identifier for the Customer
`Calendar Fk`:  Foreign Key of dimension `D_Calendar` in the fact table

```
+----------+--------------+-------------+
| Visit Id | Customer Key | Calendar FK |
+----------+--------------+-------------+
|        1 | John         |   20170101  |
|        2 | John         |   20180101  |
|        3 | John         |   20180101  |
|        4 | John         |   20190101  |
|        5 | Mark         |   20170101  |
|        6 | Mark         |   20180101  |
|        7 | Jack         |   20190101  |
+----------+--------------+-------------+
```

#### 2. Goal:

Create a Time Intelligence Year-To-Date measure that:
-   regardless of slicers selection on dimension calendar
-   count the number of distinct patients who visited the shop in the Year-To-Date
-   keep the interaction with `D_Calendar` such that I can correctly include in the matrix attribute from that dimension

#### 3. Expected Result:

Regardless of slicers filters on `D_Calendar` (e.g. D_Calendar[Year] = 2017)
we obtain the following result:

```
+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------------+
| Visit Id | Customer Key| Calendar FK | Measure YTD | D_Calendar[Year] |
+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------------+
|        4 | John        |    20190101 |           1 |             2019 |
|        7 | Jack        |    20190101 |           1 |             2019 |
+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------------+
```

#### 4. Current situation

```
+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------------+
| Visit Id | Customer Key| Calendar FK | Measure YTD | D_Calendar[Year] |
+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------------+
|        4 | John        |    20190101 |           1 |             2017 |
|        7 | Jack        |    20190101 |           1 |             2017 |
+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------------+
```

**The problem** is that `D_Calendar[Year]` in the matrix takes the value of the slicer,
and not the value associated to the `F_Visits[Calendar FK]`.

Where Measure YTD is defined as:

```
Measure YTD =
VAR vDateFrom = 20190101
VAR vDateTo = VALUE ( FORMAT ( ( TODAY () ), "YYYYMMDD" ) )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'F_Visits'[Customer Key] ),
        ALL ( D_Calendar ),
        KEEPFILTERS ( D_Calendar[Year] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'F_Visits'[Calendar FK] ),
            'F_Visits'[Calendar FK] >= vDateFrom
                && 'F_Visits'[Calendar FK] <= vDateTo
        )
    )
```

Comment: You want your dimension table to not be filtered by slicers on that table? Why do you want slicers that don't do anything?

Comment: I want two things:    
1. slicers filtering D_Calendar must not have any affect in calculating the `Measure YTD`    
2. The field of D_Calendar when added into the visualization must be the one defined by the relationship between Fact and Dimension using Calendar FK.
Am I clear?